# Wanting to set up a VNC connection between my Linux Laptop and Windows desktop

Tags: vnc

So I recently received a new laptop and loaded up ubuntu on it. I take it with me to class so I can work on my projects away from my desk at home. However, I was hoping I could find a way to be able to VNC into my desktop (Windows 7) at home wherever I am. I cannot seem to figure out how to set this up though, and any pointers would be much appreciated. I already downloaded a VNC server on my Windows 7 box, but I would like to be able to connect when not in the same wireless network (if possible).

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

To do this securely, you have at least 3 options:

1. VNC over Secure Shell (SSH)
2. Real VNC Personal edition ($30) which has security options
3. Remmina Remote Desktop Client

VNC over Secure Shell requires the most work of you. You'll need to setup a SSH Server, VNC server, and forward the port on your router to the SSH server.

Real VNC Personal edition is apparently much easier since the security is built in.

Remmina Remote Desktop Client allows you to connect directly to your Windows 7 PC using RDP (assuming you're running Win7 Pro or higher; Home edition doesn't have RDP.)

How you do each one is a whole post in and of itself, but you can Google the answers pretty easily. Hope this helps.

Comment: Awesome, thanks a lot. Yeah unfortunetely I have the darn Home edition, or else I would be happily using me some RDP. Does Real VNC have a free edition? (Extremely poor college student, :/).

Comment: Nevermind, I googled it, I forgot google existed. Thanks for the heads up, I will try this program out. Know of any tutorials that can be used to help me get it set up?

Comment: @bross: when you figure it out, please post back here as an Answer so that other people can learn how to do it.